# Calculate the travel time from one point to the other on Anylogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am developing a logistics simulation in the factory by Anylogic. It's a pick up and delivery problem, where the AGVs need to pick up the parcel and deliver to the target location. All the AGVs are traveling following paths. The paths have different speed limits.

My goal is to reduce the time of traffic jam or waiting time for jobs to be picked up.

I have the leading time, job delivered time - job generated time.
But I from here, I want to identify the time of traffic jam or waiting time.
Is there a way to calculate the time from one spot to the other considering different speed limit of paths without waiting time or traffic jam? So that I could subtract this from leading time.

Let me know if I need to clarify something.

Answer (score 0):

There is no build-in way to do this, you have to do it yourself. I have 3 ideas:

1. You compute this mathematically in the model yourself, i.e. write a function that computes the length of the total path and you have the ideal speed already, voila
2. You run a separate experiment and turn off all speed limits and other traffic: record the time in that ideal case and use that to compare
3. Similarly, you could do this in the same experiment during a warmup period: drive a fake transporter along the path and compute the perfect durations

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I think I will choose the number 3 idea. I want to accurately calculate the travel time considering the speed limits. But I think it will be challenging because I have 468 destinations. It will take a lot of time to compute all the combinations.

Comment: Do it once separately and save it in a dbase for fast lookups?

Comment: I appreciate your help! I have gained all the distances.